# Android: State management seems wrong

Tags: android

Lets say we have activities A, B. A starts B and passes an Intent Extra "id". Now the weird-ness only seems to happen with certain actions.

Start App

A calls B passes Extra: id 1

While in B press the home button.

Find the app icon and click on it.

A calls B but this time I pass in Extra: id 2

Now in B when it prints out the id it is 1 even though I specified id 2.

From further analysis it doesn't seem to be getting the new Intent, it seems to be using the old Intent, and the second time in doesn't seem to be calling the onCreate it goes straight to onRestart. So my question is, is there a way to onRestart have it get the correct Intent Extras? It seems to be grabbing the old saved extras.

I am sorry if this is hard to follow, I will see if I can get a small sample app put together that demonstrates this.

**EDIT** It appears this scenerio is not normal, and it is caused because in my AndroidManifest.xml I had my activities with the property android:launchMode="singleInstance" once I removed this it began acting as described by Rich.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press the Home button, B is still active.  So, the next time you press your app's icon, all it's doing is resuming activity B.  It's not starting A and redirecting to B as it did the first time.

Your best option is to maintain your state in a persistent storage (SharedPreferences, Sqlite, file, etc) so that you don't rely on the Intent extras being passed around.  You can already see that this is too clumsy of a method to rely on.

The quick and dirty way to do it is to kill activity B when the user navigates away from it (thereby making sure that the next time your icon is pressed it loads Activity A first).  Here's the code for doing that, but I definitely recommend saving state properly as described above over a solution like this.

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: I can see it loading A though, and than on A there is a button I push that calls B. And that call to B sets up the Intent with the extras, but it is like you are describing it is just using its previous intent and extras. Doesn't this seem wrong?

Comment: So I created a small sample app and it doesn't not behave quite the same. In my small sample app if I hit the home button and than hit my app icon it takes me straight to B, but in my actual app it does not behave like that, it takes me to A NOT B. So what is wrong with my actual app?

Comment: I think that regardless of why, unless you explicitly kill off Activity B, you might be getting the same instance of it.  Maybe that's why you still have the old intent.  You can override onNewIntent and see if that's getting hit and if it's getting the new data.  BUT...the bottom line is, when you're working with state, don't count on intents.  If you put a value in a SharedPreference and then read that value (for example), you're guaranteed to get the right value.  I'd say that's a better system than trying to mold the intent system to make it maintain state.

Comment: So let me just recap to make sure I understand. The your suggestion is to not use the built in Extra feature of the Intents, and instead use the shared preferences. The only problem I see with that is Shared Preferences can't do everything the Intent Extras can for example, the Intent you can serialize an object and pass that through as an extra. But you can't serialize an object and store it in the Shared Prefs, any thought?

Comment: I use Extras for transient information, not for "state".  If I need the app to basically remember something later on, I don't rely on intent extras.  Like, if I'm in a list of items and I need to navigate to the details screen of one of the items...I stuff the item id in an intent extra.  However, if the user makes some kind of selection and I need to remember that selection later on, I use some kind of persistent storage...the easiest of which to use is SharedPrefs.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know I figured out why it was not acting like you described, it was because my activities had the property android:launchMode="singleInstance" in the AndroidManfest.xml. Once I removed that it started acting normal and I am okay with how it is handling the state.